# adverse selection, struggle to begin

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, game-theory, economics

I'm started to work on this exercise but I don't know to continue. Here is the excercise, I'm not sure if i should use log function or just simple equation.
Consider a trade set up in which a company sells ice cream to its customers.
Producing ice cream is costly: it costs $^2 − \frac 14$ to produce  units of ice cream, () = $^2 − \frac 14$
Consumers have a different valuations for ice cream: type 1 consumers moderately like ice cream and have valuation v1(x) =$^2√$, where x is the quantity of ice cream consumed, while type 2 consumers absolutely love ice cream and have valuation v2(x) = √. If consumers get no ice cream, both types receive the same utility v1(0) = v2(0) = 0.

1. Assume the firm has full information on customer types.
   Depending on customer types, what price does the firm choose to maximize its profits?
   What quantity does the firm produce to maximize its profits?
   Find the optimal prices and the profit of the firm.
   Thank you a lot for helping me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: okay sorry, thank you for the recommendation!

Comment: Also, please edit your query with [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  I do not want to have to guess at the meaning of "it costs 2 − 1 to produce  units".

Comment: What's the difference between the two valuations, $v_1$ and $v_2$? It's a little tough to tell given how it's formatted.

Comment: v1 is for consumer 1 and v2 for the second consumer.. I only have this information

Comment: I have it formated just like I've received and since I'm struggling with this I cant give you more information

Comment: Can you go back to the source of the problem (e.g. a teacher) and get more information?  For example, see scoopfaze's comment (above).